# Issues generating .ppt for web

Tags: firefox, powerpoint, vml

I'm currently working on a web project where is showed a slider generated by PowerPoint.
The problem is about the rendering on IE >= 8 and Firefox. It is not working. But it is fine on IE 5. I have read that it is not working because the slider was generated by PowerPoint 2007 so it suits for IE 5 and not for recents versions like IE 8 or Firefox.
I do not know how to fix it. I have tried to generate it from PowerPoint 2010 with Microsoft Visual Basic but it is still not working. Does someone have an idea?

ps: the generated code uses vml which is not use anymore because it was replaced for svg.

Answer (score 0):

Save as Web page is a deprecated feature so you can expect to run into issues using it on newer versions of the browser. I would recommend looking at alternatives rather than trying to 'fix' it.

Comment: That what I was thinking but I am short on time and I thought it could exist a solution. When you talk about alternatives, could you give some examples please? Thanks